# How do I create a busy handler in sqlite3 using Deno?

Tags: sqlite, deno

I have multiple processes writing to sqlite db simultaneously using this library: https://github.com/dyedgreen/deno-sqlite

I tried setting `PRAGMA busy_timeout = 30000` but that didn't fix my problem.

I have one long running process that queries db sequentially in a loop and if I run that, the whole app freezes and users can no longer read from db.

I read something about creating an sqlite_busy_handler. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

SQlite doesn't really allow concurrent writes, you can get something close if you use the WAL. https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/begin-concurrent/doc/begin_concurrent.md